# substantial vs. numerous

Tags: word-usage, differences, synonyms

these two words seem very similar, 'substantial' says in the dic.that 'large in amount or number', numerous says that 'many'. 
Do they have differences in contexts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numerous can only be large in number, not in amount.

> You can have numerous people visit you, some of those people might be
>   substantial [ie large in size].
>
> You can have substantial people visit you, individually those people
>   cannot be numerous.

To use substantial to mean a large number it is usually preceded or followed by the word '*number*'.

> He had a substantial number of stamps in his collection.
>
> The number of stamps in his collection was substantial

.

There is also the possibility that *'There was a substantial crowd*' is understood to mean there was a large number of people in the crowd, but it really means *'the crowd (itself) was large'*

Comment: What is the difference between number and amount? I always consider them as the synonym.

Comment: @visionarylu In this context amount is used to mean 'volume, size or total' where number is an 'individual item count'. Along the same lines as 'what number did you get? / how many did you get?' asking for the specific number of items but 'what amount did you get? / how much did you get?' could be answered with 'half a bag' or 'two full bags' without specifying how many individual items constitute 'a bag's worth'